# Is there a way to detect speaker sound activity in real time using Python?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

All I want to do is create a program that will execute a piece of code when ANY sound from my current default speakers is detected. Is this possible with Python?

Comment: What do you mean by detecting sound, Any sound means background sound or human voice.Idk what you are excepting, but you can check energy change in signal,

Comment: System sound. Not a human voice or any sound in the background irl. Sounds that the default speakers of the computer pick up.